# Creating gap in polyline using QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, editing

I have a polyline that I need to make some gaps in at some locations, by cutting this part inside the red box, and leaving a gap in this particular location for instance.

How can I do that in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: Does the red box exist in another layer?

Comment: No, it does not, I just drew it over the screenshot for clarification.

Comment: Have a look at the advanced digitizing toolbox, there you made divide objects.

Answer (score 3):

1. Toggle Editing
   [image: step_1]
2. Select Feature that has to be edited
   [image: step_2]
3. Draw an area where a gap has to occur with using the [`'Split Features'`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#split-features) from the [`'Advanced Digitizing Toolbar'`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#advanced-digitizing)
   [image: step_3]
4. Get a feature where the gap has to be made
   [image: step_4]
5. Delete this feature
   [image: step_5]

---

***Alternatives:***

- Creating additional layer (polygons or polylines) and then applying [`'Difference'`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#difference) between initial polylines and the additional layer

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to advanced digitizing toolbox is to use the **Difference** algorithm.

Before using it, you must have 2 layers:

- your line layer
- your box layer

[image]